# Using fancy indexing to get one value from each column of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a two dimensional numpy array,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(5,5)
```

and a one dimensional list of indices,

```
b = np.array([0,4,2,3,3])
```

What I want to do is produce an array of values of `a` which looks like:

```
[a[b[0],0], a[b[1],1], a[b[2],[2]], a[b[3],3], a[b[4],4]]
```

Now, I know I can achieve this using `python`'s

```
[a[b[i], i] for i in range(5)]
```

but that causes two problems for me:

1. It is much much slower than operations performed in "pure `numpy`". I figure that can be avoided by some fancy use of `numpy.choose`, but that still leaves me with the second problem
2. In later parts of my procedure, I actually want to change values of `a` in the appropriate places, i.e. I pruduce a vector (array) `x` of size `5` and then set `a[b[i],i]` to `x` for all five falues of `i`.

At the moment, I do this using a `for` loop:

```
x = np.random.rand(5)
for i in range(5):
    a[b[i], i] = x[i]
```

But I have the feeling this can be done more quickly. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting:

```
>>> a = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> rows = b = np.array([0,4,2,3,3])
>>> cols = np.arange(len(b))
>>> [a[b[i], i] for i in range(5)]
[0, 21, 12, 18, 19]
>>> a[rows, cols]
array([ 0, 21, 12, 18, 19])
```

Setting:

```
>>> a[rows, cols] = 69
>>> a
array([[69,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 69, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 69, 69],
       [20, 69, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> a[rows, cols] = np.array([-111, -111, -222, -333, -666])
>>> a
array([[-111,    1,    2,    3,    4],
       [   5,    6,    7,    8,    9],
       [  10,   11, -222,   13,   14],
       [  15,   16,   17, -333, -666],
       [  20, -111,   22,   23,   24]])
```

Comment: Damn, I was so close. Because cols were simply a range from 0 to 4, I simply wrote `a[rows, :]` thinking it was the same... Thank you.

Comment: `np.array(range(5)) -----> np.arange(5)`

Comment: Yes, you were close.  You would use `a[rows, :]` to _reorder_ the rows of `a`.  In this context, the `:` means "take all columns" whereas what you want is "take one column" ..

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(5,5)
>>> b = np.array([0,4,2,3,3])
>>> b
array([[ 0.4564633 ,  0.72926453,  0.74926462,  0.41773619,  0.46413324],
       [ 0.17443626,  0.82383088,  0.39718456,  0.84513223,  0.68757984],
       [ 0.90550232,  0.39838411,  0.88410946,  0.27235604,  0.83179862],
       [ 0.44378375,  0.37845376,  0.52914614,  0.38773563,  0.80787528],
       [ 0.44378375,  0.37845376,  0.52914614,  0.38773563,  0.80787528]])
...
>>> a[b,range(b.shape[0])]
array([ 0.4564633 ,  0.82383088,  0.88410946,  0.38773563,  0.80787528])
```